# How to define a wildcard pattern using cerl:c_clause

Tags: compilation, programming-languages, erlang

I'm trying to compile some personal language to erlang. I want to create a function with pattern matching on clauses.

This is my data :

```
Data =
    [ {a, <a_body> }
    , {b, <b_body> }
    , {c, <c_body> }
    ].
```

This is what i want :

```
foo(a) -> <a_body>;
foo(b) -> <b_body>;
foo(c) -> <c_body>;
foo(_) -> undefined. %% <- this
```

I do that at the moment :

```
MkCaseClause =
    fun({Pattern,Body}) ->
        cerl:c_clause([cerl:c_atom(Pattern)], deep_literal(Body))
    end,
WildCardClause = cerl:c_clause([ ??? ], cerl:c_atom(undefined)),
CaseClauses = [MkCaseClause(S) || S <- Data] ++ [WildCardClause],
```

So please help me to define `WildCardClause`. I saw that if i call my compiled function with neither a nor b nor c it results in `** exception error: no true branch found when evaluating an if expression in function ...`.

When i print my Core Erlang code i get this :

```
'myfuncname'/1 =
    fun (Key) ->
        case Key of
          <'a'> when 'true' -> ...
          <'b'> when 'true' -> ...
          <'c'> when 'true' -> ...
        end
```

So okay, `case` is translated to `if` when core is compiled. So i need to specify a `true` clause as in an `if` expression to get a pure wildcard. I don't know how to do it, since matching `true` in an `if` expression and in a `case` one are different semantics. In a case, `true` is not a wildcard.

And what if i would like match expressions with wildcards inside like `{sometag,_,_,Thing} -> {ok, Thing}`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do this

```
...
WildCardVar = cerl:c_var('_Any'),
WildCardClause = cerl:c_clause([WildCardVar], cerl:c_atom(undefined)),
...
```

It should work for inner wildcards too, but one has to be careful to give different variable names to each `_` wildcard since only multiple `_` do not match each other, variables do.

```
f(X,_, _ ) %% matches f(a,b,c)
f(X,_X,_X) %% doesn't
```

Comment: accepting my own answer because, after further research, that is how erlang does it. And because it's the only answer :)